# How to spawn one dummy for each "d" in the message string?

Tags: text, roblox

Im working on a script building game, I have the executor etc done. 
However, I have one problem. 
To spawn a test dummy, you say pse/d
You can spawn no more than one dummy, how would I make it so if you say pse/d d d d, it spawns as many dummies as there is in the message

EG:
pse/d (Spawns 1 dummy)
pse/d d d d (Spawns 4 dummies)

Current code:

````
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(p) 
p.Chatted:connect(function(msg) 
msg = msg:lower()
if (msg == prefix.."d") then  if (p.Character ~= nil) then 
    local d=game.ServerStorage.Dummy:Clone()
    d.Parent=workspace.Debris
    d:MoveTo(p.Character:FindFirstChild'HumanoidRootPart'.Position)
end
end 
end) 
end) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using string.sub first to check if the command prefix is correct then to get external arguments.

**--> CODE**

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local CommandPrefix = "!call" -- Your Prefix
local PrefixLength = #CommandPrefix -- string is basically an array of characters therefor # operator will return it's length

local function PlayerChatted(Message)
    Message = string.lower(Message)
    
    local Pattern = string.sub(Message, 1, PrefixLength) 
    
    if Pattern == CommandPrefix then --ends the scope if Command Prefix is not valid

        local Amount = string.sub(Message, PrefixLength+1, #Message)
        Amount = tonumber(Amount)
        
        if not Amount > 0 then return end
        
        for i = 1, Amount do
            -- create clones of dummies
        end
        
    end
end


Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    Player.Chatted:Connect(PlayerChatted)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use `string.split()` to get a table return of items inside a string.

*Note: This will only work if you separate the d's with spaces(or any other character)*

### Code

```
local function PlayerChatted(msg)
    msg = string.lower(msg)

    if string.find(msg, "pse/") then
        msg = string.gsub(msg, "pse/") -- Gets rid of the prefix from the message
        local dTable = string.split(msg, "") -- Splits the string into a table using a seperator (" ")

        if #dTable > 0 then -- Making sure there are more than 0 d's
            for i=1, #dTable, 1 do
                -- Clone your dummies here
            end
        end
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.Chatted:Connect(PlayerChatted)
end
```